# Implementing a protocol method in a base class, while subclasses implement other protocol methods gives "redundant conformance" error

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I have three `NSViewControllers` that conform to `NSOutlineViewDelegate`, and implement the same protocol (delegate) methods

```
extension MyViewController1: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {}
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}

extension MyViewController2: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {}
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}

extension MyViewController3: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {}
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}
```

But all 3 of them have the same implementation for

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {}
```

---

So the idea was to make a base class, `BaseViewController`, then have it also conform to `NSOutlineViewDelegate`

```
extension BaseViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {}
}
```

Then make each `ViewController` inherit from base

```
class MyViewController1: BaseViewController {}
```

but because each `ViewController` has a different implementation for the other signature, `-viewFor`, they would still need to conform to `NSOutlineViewDelegate`

```
extension MyViewController1: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}

extension MyViewController2: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}

extension MyViewController3: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
  func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {}
}
```

But, doing this gives this error:

> Redundant conformance of 'MyViewController1' to protocol
>   'NSOutlineViewDelegate'

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do and keep the compiler happy?

Comment: The subclasses already conform to the protocol by way of subclassing a class that conforms to it, you can just implement the protocol method in the subclass without specifying that they conform to the protocol again

Comment: derp, brain fart.  that did it.  I confused myself because my classes were also conforming to `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`, but I didn't realize that `NSOutlineViewDelegate` protocol inherits from `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`

Comment: So I just removed `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` from my subclasses as well, and it worked out.  Thanks for the sanity-check